# How to manage global variables in Spec Flow

Tags: c#, unit-testing, bdd, specflow

I have a following test of my controller

```
[Binding]
public class RegisterUserSteps
{
    private AccountController _accountController = new AccountController();
    private ActionResult _result; 



    [When(@"the user goes to the register user screen")]
    public void WhenTheUserGoesToTheRegisterUserScreen()
    {
       _result = _accountController.Register();
    }

    [Then(@"the register user view should be displayed")]
    public void ThenTheRegisterUserViewShouldBeDisplayed()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("Register", _accountController.ViewData["Title"]);
    }
}
```

it works fine but it doesn't look good because i don't want to make global/class level variables . So what could be the alternate of these variables in spec flow . Because when we go into big application and single step file contain many scenarios then it will be a mess and will be hard to manage .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tend to use `ScenarioContext.Current["KeyName"]` so that I can define steps in different classes. See the specflow documentation: [sharing data between bindings](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Sharing-Data-between-Bindings) for more detail and some alternatives